# Is it true that a path is always either a file or a directory?

Tags: python, file, path, directory

In Python, for a specific OS (Linux, Mac or Windows), is it possible to have a path such that:

```
os.path.exists(path) == True
os.path.isfile(path) == False
os.path.isdir(path) == False
```

If so, what are the types of those paths?

Knowing this will be helpful to proper handle an input path.

This question may be implementation dependent so please give some references.

Edit. I have found such a file on Linux, which is `/dev/tty`. So the answer to this question is NO. However, it's still interesting to know whether there are other paths satisfying the above property.

Comment: Well, in windows there can be so many paths which are linked to a particular file or folder. When you delete a folder or file, the link would be dangling link. I believe that's the same case with Linux. And path.exists() returns false for dangling links. So, (assuming) that, there can be no links which can satisfy above condition.

Comment: @Prajwal I have found such a path on Linux: `/dev/tty`. Now I'm wondering whether there are more kinds of such paths. I'm not familiar with Windows and I think there needs to be reference from the OS manufacturer detailing supported file types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the concept of linking, then you know that if you delete original file, then the soft link would be broken. Which would return `false` for `path.exists()`. As both type of links would be referring some other file or folder, it checks and returns the existence of linked file or folder.

If you want to check for such broken link, then you will have to use `path.lexists()`.

But in UNIX-like systems there are special files, Sockets or named pipes which would act like normal file or folders but neither. I got to know about it from --> [here](http://www.livefirelabs.com/unix_tip_trick_shell_script/unix_operating_system_fundamentals/file-types-in-unix.htm).  So, i would have to correct my answer, those conditions exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is such possibility in a different dimension. See question comments.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question but i will explain what that commands do.

```
print(os.path.exists(path))
```

This command returns true if that path exists else it returns false even if u spell dekstop as destop. In mac os,ubuntu u should perform case-sensitive.

```
variable="c://users//stack//desktop/input.txt"
print(os.path.isfile(variable))
```

in the above case it will return true if the file exists in your device and if the path is true else it will return false.

```
 variable="c://users//stack//desktop/folder/input.txt"
 print(os.path.isdir(variable))
```

It throws false because in the above case it will check for directory.so, u have to mention like this:

```
variable="c://users//stack//desktop/folder"
print(os.path.isdir())
```

if that folder exists in your device it will return true else it will return false.